# how to get rid partitions on a USB on linux

Tags: usb, partitioning

i used a USB to boot up and install Linux and it partitioned about 4g of the USB and im not sure how i can get rid of the partition on it.

Comment: Do you wish to preserve the remaining (if any) partitions on the usb dirve?

Comment: no i want to just have the usb cleared out

Answer (score 1):

Open the terminal by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> and type in this command.

```
sudo apt-get install gparted gpart
```

then start up gpart with this command

```
sudo gparted-pkexec
```

[image]

Click on the device tab then click on new  partition table

then click on apply.

[image]

click on the unallocated  partition and press <kbd>Insert</kbd>

change the file system to ntfs or ext4. Make a Label then click add.

[image]

Then click on the tick mark then click on apply.

[image]

then when thats done click close.

Answer (score 0):

Let's learn how easy it is on the command line!

These are the steps to reformat your USB drive:

1. Get needed information about the drive.
2. Remove existing partitions.
3. Make the new partition.
4. Make the msdos fat filesystem on the partition.

So let's go.

Insert your USB drive, do **not** mount it or view it in a file manager.  Issue these commands (explanation below):

```
$ sudo parted --list | tail -10
    ...
    Model: SanDisk Cruzer Glide (scsi)
    Disk /dev/sdX: 7901MB
    Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
    Partition Table: msdos

    Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
     1      4194kB  4000MB  3996MB  primary  fat32        lba
     2      4000MB  7900MB  3900MB  primary  fat32        lba

$ sudo gparted /dev/sdX rm 1 rm 2
$ sudo parted --align optimal /dev/sdX mkpart primary fat32 4 7900
$ sudo mkfs.vfat /dev/sdX1
```

### Explanation:

Detailed explanation of the steps:

1. **Get needed information about the partition:**

   ```
   sudo parted --list | tail -20
   ```

   Lists multi-line records for the disks on your system. Your removeable drive will usually be the last in the list, hence use tail. Take note of the Disk device path (/dev/sdX), the size (7901MB), and the partition table numbers.
2. **Remove existing partitions:**

   ```
   sudo gparted /dev/sdX rm 1 rm 2
   ```

   Removes the existing partitions on the disk.  Repeat `rm N` for each partition number that you saw in the `parted -l` output.
3. **Make the new partition:**

   ```
   sudo parted --align optimal /dev/sdX mkpart primary fat32 4 7900
   ```

   Makes the new partition, starting at 4, and ending at 1 less than the size shown from `parted -l`.  (Many new memory-based drives work fastest with partitions starting at 4MB, the older ones doesn't matter so always use 4MB).
4. **Make a new filesystem on the new partition:**

   ```
   sudo mkfs.vfat /dev/sdX1
   ```

   Writes the msdos fat file system onto the new partition so you can actually mount it and view in File Manager, etc.

The device should now show up in your device notification area on the desktop.